# Key binding for org-exporters

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-export

How can I create a key binding for specific `org-export` commands?

E.g. I'd like to bind to `F9` exporting to an html file. Currently I need to hit `C-c C-e h h`.

eety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can figure out what commands are bound to the keys in the `org-export-dispatch` menu (`C-c C-e` in org-mode) by looking at the `:menu-entry` section of that backend's `(org-export-define-backend ..)` form.

As for `ox-html.el`, from the [source](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ox-html.el?id=8127b3c30d8a2217468068a73f23bfa4945573dc#n107) (org-mode git master branch), we get this:

```el
;; -- snip --
:menu-entry
'(?h "Export to HTML"
     ((?H "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html)
      (?h "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html)
      (?o "As HTML file and open"
          (lambda (a s v b)
            (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b)
              (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))
;; -- snip --
```

So you can bind `F9` to `org-html-export-to-html`. That is what is called when you do `C-c C-e h h`.

Comment: Or, to solve all such problems in the future, use a tool like [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) so you can do incremental completion on *all* commands with `helm-M-x`; search for "org export html" is sufficient for narrowing down choices to the obvious one.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong Correct. The same applies to any list completion package like `ido` or `ivy` too.